# Is CCKeyDerivationPBKDF thread safe?

Tags: python, c, concurrency, pbkdf2, commoncrypto

I'm using `CCKeyDerivationPBKDF` to generate and verify password hashes in a concurrent environment and I'd like to know whether it it thread safe. The documentation of the function doesn't mention thread safety at all, so I'm currently using a lock to be on the safe side but I'd prefer not to use a lock if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the source code of the `CCKeyDerivationPBKDF()` I find it to be "thread unsafe". While the code for `CCKeyDerivationPBKDF()` uses many library functions which are thread-safe(eg: `bzero`), most user-defined function(eg:`PRF`) and the underlying functions being called from those user-defined functions, are potentially thread-unsafe. (For eg. due to use of several pointers and unsafe casting of memory eg. in `CCHMac`). I would suggest unless they make all the underlying functions thread-safe or have some mechanism to alteast make it conditionally thread-safe, stick with your approach, or modify the `commoncrypto` code to make it thread-safe and use that code.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Lacking documentation or source code, one option is to build a test app with say 10 threads looping on calls to CCKeyDerivationPBKDF with a random selection from say 10 different sets of arguments with 10 known results.

Each thread checks the result of a call to make sure it is what is expected. Each thread should also have a usleep() call for some random amount of time (bell curve sitting on say 10% of the time each call to CCKeyDerivationPBKDF takes) in this loop in order to attempt to interleave operations as much as possible.

You'll probably want to instrument it with debugging that keeps track of how much concurrency you are able to generate. With a 10% sleep time and 10 threads, you should be able to keep 9 threads concurrent.

If it makes it through an aggregate of say 100,000,000 calls without an error, I'd assume it was thread safe. Of course you could run it for much longer than that to get greater assurances.